# Conditionally apply a function with values over a certain value

Tags: r, apply

I'm sure there is an easy solution to this but I cannot seem to output the correct values. I have a dataframe and I would like to calculate an average based on values above a certain value, in this case 150.

```
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:1000, 36*10, replace=TRUE), ncol=1))
df2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:500, 36*10, replace=TRUE), ncol=1))
df3 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:200, 36*10, replace=TRUE), ncol=1))
Example <- cbind(df1,df2,df3)
```

Similar stuff I've done leads me to think apply may be the most effective way (and I have tried to follow steps from the link below). 
http://rforpublichealth.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/the-infamous-apply-function.html. However, the outputs from the following code are faulty, with outputs being below 1 in spite of me trying to mean average values above 150.

```
test<- apply(Example,2,function(x) {mean(x > 150)})
```

Any help would be highly appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, but need to do `mean(x[x > 150])` rather than `mean(x > 150)`:

```
test<- apply(Example,2,function(x) {mean(x[x > 150])})
```

This works because `x[x > 150]` says "take all values of x where x is above 150".

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for the quick response as well (I cannot tick yet but I can in 5 minutes)

Answer (score 0):

For the mean of all the values.

```
mean(as.matrix(Example)[as.matrix(Example) > 150])
[1] 426.0402
```

By column

```
sapply(Example, function(x) mean(x[x > 150]))
      V1       V1       V1 
575.6926 332.9713 175.6809
```

Comment: Thank you for this alternative as well.

Answer (score 0):

A faster option is to use `matrix subsetting` to select the right values before computing mean by column :

```
ids <- which(Example>150,arr.ind=T)  ## first all right values are selected 
sapply(seq_len(ncol(Example)),       ## compute mean for each column
        function(x)mean(Example[ids[ids[,2]==x,]]))
```

Comment: You could fully vectorize this using `indx2 <- which(indx <- Example > 150, arr.ind = TRUE) ; rowsum(Example[indx2], indx2[, 2])/colSums(indx)`